# Converting python plugins into dll file for QGIS application?

Tags: qgis, python

How to convert the python plugins into dll files for QGIS application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.  Python is interpreted not compiled (*although pyc files are compiled but only at run time*)

What are you trying to gain by doing this.

**Note**: You can convert Python files to exes but QGIS won't understand them so it's pointless.

Comment: Hi..Nathan thanks for your answer, i just wanted to convert my plugin as dll and copy into C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\plugins :)

Comment: sir is it possible to make dll that uses qgis for mapping?